# How do you extract the user data from the xml and send it to a string?

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/

```
url = "http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.xml";
xml = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
apiResponse.InnerHtml = Server.HtmlEncode(xml);
```

**How do you extract the user data from the xml and send it to a string?
i.e convert xml to string.**

```
string name =
string id=
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<insert xml here or use variable>");
var username = doc.XPathSelectElement("/SomeNode/SomeOtherNode/@username").Value;
var id = doc.XPathSelectElement("/SomeNode/SomeOtherNode/@id").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you're using .NET 2.0, so I'm using XmlDocument in this example:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
TwitterUser user = new TwitterUser();

string url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.xml";
string xml = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);

xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

user.id = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("user/id").InnerText;
user.screen_name = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("user/screen_name").InnerText;
user.name = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("user/name").InnerText;
```